# Alternative for bulk Redirect 301 in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have some link redirects in htaccess in which every link should be added with /en after .com i.e.,

> mydomain.com, mydomain.com/abc.html

to

> mydomain.com/en, mydomain.com/en/abc.html

After some research i found that redirect 301 does it. But I think this is not perfect and permanent solution. In future if I add another URL, again I have to add it to htaccess. So can any one help me out in getting the perfect and permanent solution for this.

I have done this in my htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /about.html /en/about.html
Redirect 301 /contact-us.html /en/contact-us.html
Redirect 301 /index.html /en/index.html
Redirect 301 /locations.html /en/locations.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this single redirect rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?!en/)(.+\.html)$ /en/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

`(?!en/)` is negative lookahead to assert that URI is not already starting with `/en/`.

Comment: Thanks for your response it works but for one URL its adding more '/en' s almost 20 '/en' s.... what could be the problem

Comment: Test from a new browser to avoid caching. Also provide an example URL that is causing problem.